# Get end of string as const char * in C++

Tags: c++, string

Is it correct that in order to get a char pointer to the end of a `string` in C++ i have to do this:

```
std::string str = ...
const char * end_ptr = &*str.cend();
```

Like dereferencing, then getting the address of the expression. Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "end of a string"? Is that a pointer to the last character, or a pointer **one past** the last character (i. e. a pointer to the terminating NUL)?

Comment: Are you specifically looking for the address of where the '\0' would be if this was a c-string, or are you looking for the address of the last character of the string, '\0' not included? e.g. if str = "hello\0", the address of 'o' or '\0'?

Comment: @H2CO3 @kfsone I was thinking about the past-the-end address as used in iterations. This is what I'm getting with the `&*` method, but I'm not sure how reliable it really is.

Comment: Why do you want that pointer. There may be a better solution to your actual problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think that this is guaranteed, I'd use

```
const char* end_ptr = str.c_str() + str.size();
```

to get a pointer to the terminating `'\0'`.

Answer (score 4):

You solution is not correct. It will lead to undefined behavior. You cannot dereference [`str.cend()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/end):

> Returns an iterator to the character following the last character of the string. This character acts as a placeholder, **attempting to access it results in undefined behavior.**

You can do

```
const char* end_ptr = &str[str.size() - 1];
```

As pointed out in comment, this will be one bit short.

You can use [`std::c_str`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) to match the exact behavior you want and get a pointer to the `\0`:

> Returns a pointer to a null-terminated character array with data equivalent to those stored in the string.
>
> The pointer is such that the range `[c_str(); c_str() + size()]`

Then you just have to

```
const char* end_ptr = str.c_str() + str.size();
// or in c++11 you can use data()
```

*Assuming you have at least one character in your string.*

Comment: you are missing an addressof operator.

Comment: @H2CO3 Oh yes... That's totally true... I fixed it. Thank you for pointing this out !

Comment: That's the last character of the string, that's one byte before cend.

Comment: @kfsone I don't think that in itself is a reason for a downvote. `string::cend()` is a C++11-only member function, so it's correct to assume that OP is using C++11.

Comment: @H2CO3 I removed that part because Pierre made an edit; that said, his answer is still one byte short of value of cend. Daniel Frey has the correct answer.

Comment: @kfsone It seems to me that OP wants a pointer to the last character, not the end iterator. Assumptions are still not strong enough to justify a possibly wrong downvote.

Comment: Not the only reason: you at least annotated that it needs to check for size() not being zero.

Comment: Good edits, Pierre, downvote removed. You were working faster than I could get a feedback comment together for you on this phone :)

Comment: @kfsone Thank you for your feedback and thanks to H2CO3. My answer was incomplete :)

Answer (score -1):

Since you're dealing with char pointers and therefore C strings, the best way is probably to just use the suitable C function for this, [strchr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strchr/):

```
#include <cstring>
const char *endptr = std::strchr(str.c_str(), '\0');
```